# ng-repeat multiple repeats in JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

can someone please help me solve this problem with JSON and ng-repeat.

The API gives me this JSON:

```
[
{
    "Category1" : {
        "1111" : "Subcat1-1",
        "1114" : "Subcat1-2"
    }
},
{
    "Category2" : {
        "1112" : "Subcat2-1",
        "1113" : "Subcat2-2"
    }
},
{
    "Category3" : {
        "1115" : "Subcat3-1",
        "1116" : "Subcat3-2"
    }
},
{
    "Category4" : {
        "1117" : "Subcat4-1",
        "1118" : "Subcat4-2"
    }
}
```

]

I want the ng-repeat to have this structure:

```
<div>Category1</div>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat1-1</li>
    <li>Subcat1-2</li>
</ul>
<div>Category2</div>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat2-1</li>
    <li>Subcat2-2</li>
</ul>
<!-- ... and so on ... -->
```

I have to ng-repeat 2 times, but I dont really know how to access the data "Subcat".
Somethink like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <div>{{I need the "Category1" String here}}</div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(a,b) in itemList[item]">{{b should be the value "SubcatX-x"}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me out? Thank u for your help.

EDIT:

Just solved it by myself, 1 minute after posting this and 3 hours after trying.

Solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="(a, b) in myJson">
            {{a}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(c, d) in b">{{d}}</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it by myself, 1 minute after posting this and 3 hours after trying.

```
<div ng-repeat="(a, b) in myJson">
            {{a}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(c, d) in b">{{d}}</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the structure you wanted, you need to add a third repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
  <div ng-repeat="(a, b) in item">
    {{a}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(c, d) in b">
        {{d}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sBNlmgtDjt8IgzPU2CVJ?p=preview